# Facebook pixel for registered users

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, facebook-pixel

I'm new with FB pixel and have recently implemented this on my Asp .Net site.

I log in with the same FB account that I'm using to collect data for FB pixel.

I go to my site and create a user account using the same **email address** being used with FB. I DO NOT login using FB authentication on my site just a separate account.

I can see my email address listed within the JavaScript (in view source, plain text as FB encrypt this for me) I copied from FB (advanced version of the script). I can see events listed under the pixel management area.

How can I verify that the FB account I have logged in with and the email address I have registered with on my site is collecting data against a registered account and not an account against someone who is not registered with Facebook?

Hope this makes sense but ask questions if you would like me to clarify further.